# Can ignite C++ thin-client be used to create queryable fields (of cache)?

Tags: c++, ignite, thin-client, asqueryable, thick-client

It seems that only ignite c++ thick client is able to config the queryable fields of a cache (e.g  through a Spring configuration file), can anyone use thin client to do the same thing?

I can only create cache (using thin client) that is retrievable throught key-value api,
but not with SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the C++ thin-client does not appear to directly support *creating* tables with SQL support.

As a workaround, you could create a Java task that creates tables and [call that from your C++ client](https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/latest/cppdoc/classignite_1_1thin_1_1compute_1_1ComputeClient.html).